# Mapbox studio Legened

Tags: mapbox

I am using mapbox studio to create a a visualization that will eventually be included in a report, I want to know the best way to add a legend but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do it in studio, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You currently can’t add a legend through Mapbox Studio. All of that will have to be done through HTML/JavaScript.

[This tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-2/) is a good example of adding a legend using HTML